# getpwuid doesn't set errno

Tags: c++, linux, errno

```
    uid_t userId = getuid();
    userId = 999;               // cause error

    errno = 0;
    passwd* pw = getpwuid(userId);

    int n = errno;    // pw = NULL, n = 0
```

Running this code in Linux, I get pw = NULL (expected), and errno = 0. According to Linux documentation http://linuxmanpages.com/man3/getpwuid.3.php, getpwuid must set errno. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> ```
> ERRORS
>          0 or ENOENT or ESRCH or EBADF or EPERM or ...
>                 The given name or uid was not found.
> ```

I fail to see a problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you linked:

```
   0 or ENOENT or ESRCH or EBADF or EPERM or ...
          The given name or uid was not found.
```

So errno == 0 is perfectly valid for a uid not found.